# scss/sass and target last div border bottom

Tags: css, sass

So, I have this card group component, and within it, seperate cards. I want to remove the border bottom of all of them EXCEPT the last one. I can't solve it. I am using sass/scss

```
<CardGroup className="cardgroup">
   <Card className="card"><div>other stuff</div></Card>
   <Card className="card">stuff two<div>whatever</div></Card>
   <Card className="card">stuff three</Card> <--- KEEP BORDER BOTTOM HERE
</CardGroup>
```

I have borders on all of the children..(Card). I want to remove the Card border bottom..FROM the CardGroup. My css looks like: Keep in mind that I use hex/ing so the css names change. Of course, I will get the 'base' name, so that is why I am doing: *=card. It seems to remove all children, but also grandchildren etc... I can't seem to just target the LAST css class that contains "card" to suppress border-bottom.

I tried a couple things (ie, last-child etc..) just can't get it. Any ideas?

```css
    .cardgroup > [class*='card']:not(last-of-type)  {
        border-bottom: none;
      }


    .card {
      background-color: $white;
      border-bottom: $border200;
      border-top: $border200;
    }
```

Comment: typo :`not(last-of-type)`  --> `not(:last-of-type)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're forgetting the `:` on your `:last-of-type`. See below:

```css
.card:not(:last-of-type) {
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardgroup">
  <div class="card">
  Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `last-child` selecter for this. I created a fiddle to show you the result
https://jsfiddle.net/t3dc40fe/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `last-child` selector

```
.cardgroup > .card:last-child  {
   border-bottom: none;
 }
```

The `:last-child` selector matches every element that is the last child of its parent.

Ex: `p:last-child` is equal to `p:nth-last-child(1)`.